# Python JSON parse from second list and store as pandas dataframe as OHLC data for statistic analysis

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is the JSON output from the URL source link that is extracted using the below code (thank you for the support jezreal)

In it the time open high low close needs to be aligned in the pandas data frame as below and the time is in unix format can this also be taken care to show readable time in the same line coversion.

```
time             open    high    low      close 
1539799200       6552.03 6561.18 6536.5   6559.63
1539810000       6560.84 6578.1  6555.33  6574.52


{"Response":"Success","Type":100,"Aggregated":true,"Data":[{"time":1539799200,"close":6559.63,"high":6561.18,"low":6536.5,"open":6552.03,"volumefrom":4624.82,"volumeto":30479248.75},{"time":1539810000,"close":6574.52,"high":6578.1,"low":6555.33,"open":6560.84,"volumefrom":2368.81,"volumeto":15594716.12},{"time":1539820800,"close":6573.91,"high":6585.42,"low":6560.31,"open":6576.4,"volumefrom":3144.75,"volumeto":20776589.48},{"time":1539831600,"close":6576.48,"high":6616.27,"low":6568.41,"open":6573.91,"volumefrom":6208.05,"volumeto":40945806.05},{"time":1539842400,"close":6560.13,"high":6579.81,"low":6542.31,"open":6576.48,"volumefrom":8045.66,"volumeto":52659570.56},{"time":1539853200,"close":6546.74,"high":6566.63,"low":6541.93,"open":6560.13,"volumefrom":4540.41,"volumeto":29713532.97},{"time":1539864000,"close":6546.59,"high":6560.14,"low":6541.11,"open":6546.74,"volumefrom":5465.11,"volumeto":35723664.51},{"time":1539874800,"close":6499.07,"high":6552.18,"low":6468.72,"open":6546.59,"volumefrom":9674.57,"volumeto":63221298.41},{"time":1539885600,"close":6483.95,"high":6511.51,"low":6471.98,"open":6499.39,"volumefrom":6698.95,"volumeto":43509638.59},{"time":1539896400,"close":6488.72,"high":6497.04,"low":6445.05,"open":6483.95,"volumefrom":6947.84,"volumeto":45211014.91},{"time":1539907200,"close":6490.42,"high":6503.09,"low":6471.97,"open":6489.37,"volumefrom":4423.34,"volumeto":28794167.92},{"time":1539918000,"close":6461.14,"high":6494.75,"low":6460.48,"open":6490.42,"volumefrom":5162.67,"volumeto":33678228.34},{"time":1539928800,"close":6470.87,"high":6481.89,"low":6449.36,"open":6461.39,"volumefrom":6860.66,"volumeto":44505867.3},{"time":1539939600,"close":6478.1,"high":6491.73,"low":6466.29,"open":6471.4,"volumefrom":4692.68,"volumeto":30512532.85},{"time":1539950400,"close":6465.38,"high":6480.59,"low":6450.43,"open":6478.46,"volumefrom":4686.65,"volumeto":30447205.19},{"time":1539961200,"close":6474.23,"high":6490.73,"low":6461.29,"open":6465.38,"volumefrom":4031.97,"volumeto":26204586.39},{"time":1539972000,"close":6463.07,"high":6491.25,"low":6456.37,"open":6475.34,"volumefrom":4705.28,"volumeto":30503295.6},{"time":1539982800,"close":6469.28,"high":6481.32,"low":6461.01,"open":6463.07,"volumefrom":2036.37,"volumeto":13209201.82},{"time":1539993600,"close":6475.71,"high":6490.09,"low":6457.34,"open":6469.28,"volumefrom":2819.04,"volumeto":18270501.18},{"time":1540004400,"close":6472.47,"high":6480.5,"low":6466.73,"open":6475.71,"volumefrom":1283.87,"volumeto":8371731.17},{"time":1540015200,"close":6492.87,"high":6514.63,"low":6469.83,"open":6472.48,"volumefrom":5611.77,"volumeto":36422917.95},{"time":1540026000,"close":6492.14,"high":6499.02,"low":6481.22,"open":6493.1,"volumefrom":2627.8,"volumeto":17028821.55},{"time":1540036800,"close":6485.75,"high":6503.24,"low":6481.35,"open":6492.86,"volumefrom":1688.73,"volumeto":11050199.06},{"time":1540047600,"close":6474.56,"high":6491.55,"low":6467.06,"open":6485.75,"volumefrom":2174.05,"volumeto":14174026.53},{"time":1540058400,"close":6449.62,"high":6620.03,"low":6395.45,"open":6474.84,"volumefrom":1618.05,"volumeto":10591087.07},{"time":1540069200,"close":6490.56,"high":6645.2,"low":6409.58,"open":6449.62,"volumefrom":1720.45,"volumeto":11276563.25},{"time":1540080000,"close":6523.14,"high":6537.85,"low":6474.47,"open":6490.6,"volumefrom":3119.01,"volumeto":20414111.11},{"time":1540090800,"close":6512.33,"high":6527.19,"low":6505.1,"open":6523.14,"volumefrom":1428.44,"volumeto":9410771.05},{"time":1540101600,"close":6521.18,"high":6531.31,"low":6505.24,"open":6512.33,"volumefrom":1154.44,"volumeto":7602973.18},{"time":1540112400,"close":6532.94,"high":6547.63,"low":6519.27,"open":6521.06,"volumefrom":2493.15,"volumeto":16460093.6},{"time":1540123200,"close":6553.24,"high":6557.39,"low":6528.7,"open":6532.94,"volumefrom":2073.1,"volumeto":13648215},{"time":1540134000,"close":6541.43,"high":6555.82,"low":6536.35,"open":6554.68,"volumefrom":1961.45,"volumeto":12892589.57},{"time":1540144800,"close":6540.79,"high":6544.87,"low":6536.15,"open":6541.47,"volumefrom":1343.65,"volumeto":8836846.92},{"time":1540155600,"close":6509.87,"high":6544.03,"low":6505.93,"open":6541.09,"volumefrom":2446.25,"volumeto":16018328.61},{"time":1540166400,"close":6512.88,"high":6521.91,"low":6490.91,"open":6509.87,"volumefrom":2808.98,"volumeto":18326028.18},{"time":1540177200,"close":6513.97,"high":6531.23,"low":6506.3,"open":6512.89,"volumefrom":2789.67,"volumeto":18120642.6},{"time":1540188000,"close":6490.33,"high":6523.38,"low":6486.56,"open":6513.94,"volumefrom":4780.49,"volumeto":30938881.1},{"time":1540198800,"close":6487.27,"high":6495.84,"low":6483.85,"open":6490.37,"volumefrom":4514.42,"volumeto":29184642.35},{"time":1540209600,"close":6475.55,"high":6487.75,"low":6460.38,"open":6487.27,"volumefrom":4501.18,"volumeto":29396797.66},{"time":1540220400,"close":6482.89,"high":6488.84,"low":6475,"open":6475.55,"volumefrom":3796.89,"volumeto":24634623.93},{"time":1540231200,"close":6492.22,"high":6492.82,"low":6467.97,"open":6482.92,"volumefrom":4610.63,"volumeto":29857061.51},{"time":1540242000,"close":6483.23,"high":6493.26,"low":6480.04,"open":6492.58,"volumefrom":3436.8,"volumeto":22308237.06},{"time":1540252800,"close":6486.84,"high":6490.71,"low":6474.37,"open":6484.32,"volumefrom":3630.53,"volumeto":23554296.71},{"time":1540263600,"close":6478.56,"high":6486.84,"low":6463.04,"open":6486.84,"volumefrom":3944.16,"volumeto":25539762.26},{"time":1540274400,"close":6470.69,"high":6480.85,"low":6466.25,"open":6478.56,"volumefrom":5576.22,"volumeto":36107314.56},{"time":1540285200,"close":6450.77,"high":6475.53,"low":6438.99,"open":6470.79,"volumefrom":6005.54,"volumeto":38830627.57},{"time":1540296000,"close":6465.51,"high":6486.24,"low":6447.5,"open":6450.7,"volumefrom":4398.41,"volumeto":28561892.47},{"time":1540306800,"close":6465.95,"high":6482.38,"low":6464.26,"open":6465.94,"volumefrom":3560.77,"volumeto":23168362.41},{"time":1540317600,"close":6470.21,"high":6496.2,"low":6464.86,"open":6466.89,"volumefrom":4605.72,"volumeto":29864291.15},{"time":1540328400,"close":6470.22,"high":6479.57,"low":6464.04,"open":6470.39,"volumefrom":2350.25,"volumeto":15286746.48},{"time":1540339200,"close":6482.54,"high":6482.86,"low":6465.73,"open":6470.63,"volumefrom":2430.51,"volumeto":15796676.89},{"time":1540350000,"close":6519.77,"high":6538.35,"low":6479.98,"open":6483.11,"volumefrom":6768.62,"volumeto":44074393.78},{"time":1540360800,"close":6506.2,"high":6524.39,"low":6501.02,"open":6519.77,"volumefrom":5465.81,"volumeto":35521973.45},{"time":1540371600,"close":6501.81,"high":6521.51,"low":6498.7,"open":6506.2,"volumefrom":4070.56,"volumeto":26564829.78},{"time":1540382400,"close":6507.85,"high":6511.7,"low":6498.39,"open":6502.6,"volumefrom":4094.13,"volumeto":26658796.94},{"time":1540393200,"close":6495.16,"high":6508.67,"low":6481.44,"open":6507.9,"volumefrom":4215.83,"volumeto":27453667.29},{"time":1540404000,"close":6491.62,"high":6499.79,"low":6475.42,"open":6494.86,"volumefrom":4470.52,"volumeto":29077607.29},{"time":1540414800,"close":6476.25,"high":6494.04,"low":6469.75,"open":6492.04,"volumefrom":2595.67,"volumeto":16920186.4},{"time":1540425600,"close":6459.38,"high":6497.9,"low":6432.3,"open":6476.52,"volumefrom":6492.6,"volumeto":42043551.31},{"time":1540436400,"close":6464.79,"high":6470.14,"low":6450.03,"open":6459.38,"volumefrom":3505.93,"volumeto":22669303.87},{"time":1540447200,"close":6470.36,"high":6470.36,"low":6463.61,"open":6464.79,"volumefrom":101.44,"volumeto":658683.69}],"TimeTo":1540447200,"TimeFrom":1539799200,"FirstValueInArray":true,"ConversionType":{"type":"direct","conversionSymbol":""}}
```

did some try and getting error how to resolve and get the right dataframe format OHLC data.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histohour?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG'
res = requests.get(url)
j = res.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(j))
print(df[['Data'][0]['time'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add key `Data` to `json_normalize` and if necessary create index by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) :

```
df = json_normalize(j, 'Data').set_index('time')
#another solution
#df = json_normalize(j['Data']).set_index('time')
print (df.head(10))
            close  high  low  open  volumefrom  volumeto
time                                                    
1539810000    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
1539820800    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
1539831600    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
1539842400    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
1539853200    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
1539864000    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
1539874800    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
1539885600    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
1539896400    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
1539907200    0.0   0.0    0     0           0         0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas [set_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). There's no need for `json_normalize` in this case, i.e.:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histohour?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG'
try:
    df = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url).json()['Data']).set_index('time')
    print(df)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

---

```
              close     high      low     open  volumefrom     volumeto
time                                                                   
1539810000  6574.52  6578.10  6555.33  6560.84     2368.81  15594716.12
1539820800  6573.91  6585.42  6560.31  6576.40     3144.75  20776589.48
1539831600  6576.48  6616.27  6568.41  6573.91     6208.05  40945806.05
1539842400  6560.13  6579.81  6542.31  6576.48     8045.66  52659570.56
...
```